# Why thread has itself a stack while sharing local variable?

Tags: c, multithreading

From my current understanding:

1. Every thread has its own stack
2. For a local variable `int a` in `main()`, it's on the stack of `main()`
3. After a thread created in `main()`, they can both access the same `a`. Wait a minute...?

What's wrong of my reasoning...

I should probably not to guess but here is it: It seems like on the perspective of the thread the parent-stack is ... global?

(I know this is probably asked before but I cannot find the exact one explaining this)

Comment: The stacks are all in the same virtual address space. So if you had a pointer to it, you could access a variable on *any* thread's stack.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: C doesn't actually require that objects with automatic storage be accessible from other threads (e.g. it admits the awful Win16 model where the same virtual address range is used for each thread's stack), but POSIX does require it.

Comment: @R..: I thought Win16 didn't have address space isolation for processes, nevermind for threads.

Comment: @R.. Where does C define threads outside of POSIX?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: *7.26 Threads <threads.h>*

Comment: @BenVoigt: It might have been Win32S running on Win16 that had that model. I don't recall exactly but I know they had something like that on Windows at some point in history.

Comment: @R..: Might you be thinking of the implied segment for data pointers in tiny/small/medium memory models (which only applied to NEAR pointers, FAR pointers would still be able to access variables in other thread stacks just fine)?

Comment: Can you please show your code? Are you passing by a pointer or by value? I could help if you could show the code you're using. I want to see the declaration of int a, starting the thread and initializing it (what thread library/functions are you using?) and the part of thread program that accesses int a.

Answer (score 0):

variables that are inside a function are called local variables.

```
void function_1(){ int a,b;}
```

A and B can only be used inside this function. After the function is called, the variables will be destroyed.

Next example:

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main()
{
    int a = 100;    
    {
        /*  variable a declared in this block is
            completely different from variable
            declared outside.  */
        int a = 10;  
        printf("Inner a = %d\n", a);
    }    
    printf("Outer a = %d\n", a);    
    // signal to operating system everything works fine
    return 0;
}
```

a can be used inside main()

Global Variable:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void func_1();
int a, b = 10;  // declaring and initializing global variables
int main()
{
    printf("Global a = %d\n", a);
    printf("Global b = %d\n\n", b);

    func_1();

    // signal to operating system program ran fine
    return 0;
}
void func_1()
{
    printf("From func_1() Global a = %d\n", a);
    printf("From func_1() Global b = %d\n\n", b);
}
```

A and B can be used inside main() and func_1().